# connecting to services on docker host from docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

Apologies for asking two unrelated questions.

1. what is the best way of accessing the host machine of the docker container (i.e. I am trying to access a kafka instance running on the host, from my docker container so that I can publish some messages)
2. when I run `docker run .....` on an image which I've modified that may have an issue/syntax error, it will naturally not start - is there a log file anywhere that I would be able to take a look at to debug the issue. (this question is somewhat related to the 1st question, since I did what was suggested on another post, but the image is still not starting)

Answer (score 1):

1. This is an ongoing discussion on what to use and what not, I don't really know what is best. Using the `docker run --net="host"` is pretty easy but can be dangerous. See [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).
2. Use `docker logs containerid` or lookup the raw data in `/var/lib/docker/containers/containerid/` for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have no problem connecting to the host using the local lan interface ip address. Suppose you have a host with ip 192.168.0.1:

   docker run --rm -ti ubuntu bash
   ping 192.168.0.1

should give you a response.

2. You can use docker logs to see the standard output of your container.